# SQL Find similar word and order by matching

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can i find similar word in sql? for example:

i have those words -

> hell, llo, hl, lh

I want to find the matching word to `"hello"` or `"helloworld"`

And the order will be by most matching letters

i tried to do with "LIKE" but it limited results

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `LOCATE` function, which returns the first character position when it finds a needle in a haystack. You could do that for each of your terms with an `IF > 0 THEN...`:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
ORDER BY
    (
    IF(LOCATE('hell', field_to_search) > 0, 1, 0)
    + IF(LOCATE('llo', field_to_search) > 0, 1, 0)
    + IF(LOCATE('hl', field_to_search) > 0, 1, 0)
    + IF(LOCATE('lh', field_to_search) > 0, 1, 0)
    ) DESC
```

If `field_to_search` contains (case insensitively) all four terms, it will have 4 in that order by field, and zero if it doesn't match any etc. This won't limit your results like `WHERE field_to_search LIKE '%hell%'` etc.

Using the `IF(LOCATE` structure will also allow you to give different weighting to different search terms, e.g. if it matches `hell` you might give it 4 points, `llo` might give it 3. So it could theoretically match `hl` and `lh` but not `hell` or `llo` and still come up above a term that matches the top two (if you weight the bottom two higher than the top etc).

Documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Answer (score 0):

You may have some luck with [fulltext indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: The link is good (it is to full-text searching) but the description here is very limited.  YOu likely need to use fulltext searching functionality using (`MATCH ... AGAINST ...1 syntax) which would require a fulltext index against the columns being matched.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT words.*
FROM words
WHERE 'hello' LIKE CONCAT('%', word, '%')
ORDER BY
  LENGTH(word) DESC
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5102/1). Please notice that this query won't be very fast, as it can't make use of an index.